C++ GoogleTest INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P generate sequence numbers for test cases
How to effectively use C++ generate / generat_n / iota in INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P ::testing::Values to generate the input parameters with sequence numbers for the test cases? For example:
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(InstantationName, Suite, testing::Values(make_tuple(2, vector<long>{0, 1, 2, 3, ...} /*How to leverage the above-mentioned functions to auto-generate this sequence instead of hard-coding it?*/ ));


The example in the edit history of the question isn't a sequence of test cases, it's one case which has a sequence as part of it's state.

For that specific case, there's a dedicated Range gtest generator that creates sequences of numbers for INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P to consume:
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(InstantationName, Suite, testing::Range(start, stop, step));


Live demo

How does this work if the test case expects a mixture of both values and sequence?

@KokHowTeh - I don't answer Chameleon questions. Changing a post in a way that invalidates existing answers is bad netiquette on SO. I suggest asking a new question, and this time spend more time describing what you actually want instead of hand-waving it and then moving the goal posts.

How does that invalidate my question? I just provided more details to clarify my question. Apparently you answer based on your own assumption that the test cases only need one sequence numbers as the only input parameters and you find my update offending to you with your assumption.

And it was a terrible assumption. How does that work without defining an expected value in the input params?

@KokHowTeh - No  I answer based on the text in the question. The only terrible thing is your attitude.

If you have C++23, you can use the ranges library to construct a vector:
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(InstantationName, Suite, testing::Values(make_tuple(2, std::views::iota(0, 10) | std::ranges::to<std::vector<long>>)));

Otherwise you can call a lambda expression in place
INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(InstantationName, Suite, testing::Values(make_tuple(2, []{ 
    std::vector<long> vec(10); 
    std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end()); 
    return vec;
}())));


What's co_yield?

How does this work both individual values and number sequence in a single definition?

See, this is what you get when you reward someone who moves the goal posts, just more moving goal posts.

@KokHowTeh You can use testing::Combine to define aggregates. co_yield is a keyword that makes the enclosing function a coroutine. In this case it demonstrates making the arbitrary sequence 42, 10, 11, ..., 19

This is answer which makes sence in the future. 1. AFAIK std::generator currently  is supported only by gcc14 since 6th May. 2. I do not think gtest supports coroutines, at least it fails here: https://godbolt.org/z/nT7rMcrMx (ggc trunk is early version of gcc 14). 3. std::ranges::iota is also not well supported yet.

@KokHowTeh I've re-read the question, and it looks like you aren't asking about how to define multiple testcases, but one testcase with multiple values
